# SQL : Avoiding duplicates by comparing the consecutive rows

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Lets consider I've 10 rows of data in which there are duplicates in a column named PS_DRIVER. I need to get only one row for each value in PS_DRIVER based on the highest value in PS_Completion_TS(timestamp).
Note: Some PS_DRIVER doesn't have duplicates and in that case i need that row too.

Comment: Edit your question with the database tag,sql is just a language.

Comment: Depending on your database, you may be able to use ranking functions to get the highest value. If your database doesn't have such functions, you can use subqueries to get the same results. What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select td.PS_DRIVER
from tabDrivers td
where td.PS_Completion_TS in (select max(td2.PS_Completion_TS) 
                              from tabDrivers td2 
                              where td2.PS_DRIVER = td.PS_DRIVER  )
```